# Why is my notebook going to sleep when lid is closed even If I disabled it?

Tags: power-management, cinnamon

Here is my situation:

- I installed Xubuntu 13. 10
- I added the Cinnamon PPA and installed Cinnamon 2. 0
- I removed all the GNOME stuff, that came with Xubuntu
- Everything went fine so far...but...

These are my settings:

- In my Power settings the following is set:
- When lid is closed (on battery):**suspend**

  - When lid is closed (on AC):**do nothing**
  - In my lock settings I set that there should be a password prompt, after going to suspend/waking up

Now this strange behaviour:

If I close my lid, be it on battery or on AC power, the notebook suspends. But after waking it up, there is **no** password prompt.
If I manually activate suspend mode (special key on keyboard/system menu) there **is** a password prompt after waking up.

My question: Why is this happening? Why does the power daemon (there is only "upowerd" running) ignores my power settings? What software/settings has to be installed/set to make this work properly?

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug, ...software has them. Have you tried those settings on the default Xubuntu install?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there are not two different settings applications and one is conflicting with the other?

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson How do I find out? If I grep my processes list for "settings" there is only "cinnamon-settings-daemon" running.

Comment: @FelixHaller look under "Applications -> Settings", the System menu, and other similar app menus.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson nope :-(

Comment: I think there are a range of issues still to iron out around suspending and resuming. I have similar problems but find using ctrl+alt+backspace to shut down the desktop manager and go to the login screen to be the least problematical.

Comment: Ok...I think it's a bug, cause I found this one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1243383

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a (workaround?)-solution in a german forum:

http://www.linuxmintusers.de/index.php?PHPSESSID=ae47571e196b624a3109c83c69d26183&topic=15178.msg179264#msg179264

You have to edit the file `/etc/systemd/login.conf` and uncomment/modify the following two lines:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
```

That solved the issue for me and the system no longer ignores my cinnamon settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is already a bug issue, so it will be solved sometime in the future. For now there is and official workaround:

> "This can be adjusted in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`. Just set `HandleLidSwitch` and other the events you want handled by `systemd` to `ignore` - you have to delete `#` in the beginning of the respective lines, save, close the file, and restart."